# How to get the input of a key for a conditional in python?

Tags: python, function, input, keyboard, user-input

I want to activate a function when I press a key in my keyboard, in my case, I want to ask if the user is pressing the "return key" and if it is true, activate a function. besides, I want to activate the function at the moment of pressing the key, I don´t want to press again the key for confirmation. Help :(

I tried to use the function: input() and then search the options I have for the most situable, but I don´t find anything.

I use simply:

```
if input() == "A":
    print("oh yeah")
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly and you really only care about the return key then you can use input().

If the input function is called execution of the script will be halted until the user passes some input and this input can only happen once the user confirms it by pressing the return key.

```
input() # Execution of the script is halted until the input is confirmed

# Any code that comes after this will only be executed after the input was confirmed
```

Comment: Glad I could help  I think you may mark this question as closed.